# Css - submenus not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `nav` with some `ULs` and `LIs`. But in some `LIs` I have another `UL` to create a sub menu but the submenu is just going towards the right side.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/mxExq/).

**HTML:**

```
<header>
        <h1 style="float: left; margin-top: 2%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Naughty Mama.</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="inbox.php">Inbox</a>
            </li>
            <li>    <a href="notifications.php">Notifications</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>Notification 1</li>
                    <li>Notification 2</li>
                    <li>Notification 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    vertical-align: top;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #aaa;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I align those double nested `LIs` to left side of the main menu?

Hope I am clear.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Both the answers below seem to be right if you meant aligned to the left side of the **parent** in the menu item, align to the left side of the main menu implies that you want it to the left of the entire menu.

Comment: Yeah I know! So which one should I accept? The first one?

Comment: It depends on what you're after - aljordan's answer will apply to all of your unordered lists, but Abduls only applies to the child unordered list, and only changes the left padding. Abdul's IMO is more specific to the question asked, but the fact that you don't seem to be specifying your paddings/margins on lists indicates that you're not doing enough in that regard anyway (as different browser will interpret them differently so you should specify them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
nav ul li ul{
    padding-left:0px;}
```

Comment: Awesome :) Worked. But someone gave a little ssame answer before you so have to accept his one's :) Sorry :(

Comment: it is not about accept my answer . i just want to help u, that answer is cool but mine is more specific, targeting the specific ul not in general :)

Answer (score 1):

Reset your CSS

```
ul {  padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about doing something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mxExq/1/)?

Changes:

```
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
nav ul {
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
nav > ul { position:relative; }
nav ul li ul {
    display: block;
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: What are you after? Where do you want the sub-menu aligned?

Comment: Well, I got another answer that worked. Anyway, thanks for your precious time :)